# c# Class extender

Tags: c#

I may be way off here, but I thought I remember reading a while back that there is a way to extend an existing class and override its existing functionality.

For instance, is there a way to take LinkButton and extend it to expose a new method or property? Is there a way to override and existing method/property? Like NavigateURL?

I am not talking about subclassing, I am talking about extending. Am I way off here?

Thanks

Comment: I would do a class which inherit from what you wanna modify, then override what you're interested in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static void NavigateURL(this LinkButton lb, string url) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

each LinkButton in you project will have this method now (without the first parameter). first parameter uses the prefix 'this' and is of type that you are extending, the rest are method parameters...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! What is the method called? Object Extension?

Comment: it is called an "extension method"

Answer (score 3):

are you talking about extension methods?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a straightforward inherited class

```
public class MyLinkButton : LinkButton
{
    //you can then override any method/property (intellisense will guide you)
    public override bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Enabled = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, you can only override virtual, abstract or already overridden methods/properties in the base class.

Comment: you can do even bad thing redeclaring method with the 'new' keyword. For simple things like adding a method adding an extra class is overwork, and probably an extension method is more suitable, when there si a need to modify behaviour then yes of course.